# How to stop rotation on one axis and start rotation in new axis by using button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are three buttons given X , Y & Z while pressing X the 3d object needs to be rotated in X axis and by pressing the Y the rotation in X axis  should be stopped and start new rotation in y axis similarly on z button also. But I don't know how to stop rotation in one axis and start on new axis. You might feel this is simple , sorry I'm a newbie .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone (tell me how to) implement XY for me" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just check for the different inputs and if they are pressed rotate it along that axis? So it would be something like this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + rotSpeed, transform.rotation.eulerAngler.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
}
```

And do the same on the other axis. Im not 100% sure this will work and there might be some spelling mistakes in the code, but that should be an easy fix. Hope this is to some kind of help :)